# Android: Obtaining image URL directly from Parse

Tags: android, gridview, parse-platform, universal-image-loader

For fetching url for images from Parse, I have implemented the below codes from Parse.com's examples, as follows:

### Code:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
    // Create the array
    url_photoarraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    all_info_photoarraylist = new ArrayList<Photos>();
    try 
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("photo_database");
        query.orderByAscending("photo_id");
        ob = query.find();
        for (ParseObject photo_data : ob) 
        {
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile) photo_data.get("photo_file");
            Photos map = new Photos();
            map.set_photo_ref(image.getUrl());
            map.set_user_name((String) photo_data.get("user_name"));
            url_photoarraylist.add(map.get_photo_ref());
            all_info_photoarraylist.add(map);
        }
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Question:

While this works successfully, since I have also used `UniversalImageLoader` at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader to load Parse images to GridView, where at there it also re-download the same set of images using URL, I would like to ask whether at the above code, just to obtain the image URL directly instead of getting a ParseFile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written [here](https://parse.com/questions/pfimageview-takes-a-pffile-that-it-will-download-how-do-i-get-that-pfile), running a Parse query does not download the contents of the `PFFile`. This means that running your query to get the `PFFiles`, and then using `UniversalImageLoader` with `image.getUrl();` won't result in the image downloading twice.

Comment: thanks your reply...I have already done so by adding getURL(). Can you please put out the code in a more detailed way?

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed through your code and didn't see that. So you want to get the imageUrl without downloading the PFFile?

Comment: oh thanks a lot for your reference and clarification! this clarifies a lot as Parse will charge upon exceeding certain data usage!